# Plot two box plots with same y variable but different x variables in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataset with 3 columns. One is monthly expenditure (y-variable). Each value in this variable is categorised as either 1 or 0 under two different variables.

Data looks something like this:

```
  df_UP.q234_month_exp df_UP.LFT df_UP.LF
1                   NA         0        1
2                   NA         1        1
3                12000         1        1
4                   NA         1        1
5                20000         1        1
6                   NA         0        1
```

Data has about 1200 rows.

I want a plot which creates a box plot for 'df_UP.q234_month_exp' as y-variable for all rows of 'df_UP.LFT' which are 1, and another box plot in the same plot with same y-variable, but for all rows of 'df_UP.LF' which are 1.

How to accomplish this using ggplot2?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Something like that should work: `ggplot(dat, aes(factor(f), var)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(.~g)` where `f` and `g` are your binary variables and `var` your numeric variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(df_UP.q234_month_exp = c(NA, NA, 12000L, NA, 20000L, 
NA), df_UP.LFT = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), df_UP.LF = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

The code:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -df_UP.q234_month_exp) %>%
  filter(value==1) %>% ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = name,y = df_UP.q234_month_exp,color=name,group=name))
```

Output:

[image]